# Using PHP client to revoke a celery task using it Task ID

Tags: php, celery

I am having a problem to figure out how to revoke a celery task using its task ID in PHP. I can do that from python by using the Celery.app.Control.revoke() API.

The PHP client docs suggest using AsyncResult to revoke, but all I have is a task ID, and I feel that there should be a way to revoke it. Is it possible to do that in PHP client? Can some one give a working code for that?

### EDIT 1:

The revoke() function in PHP library is empty! It means creating AsyncResult object and then calling revoke() will do nothing!

Thanks in advance!